# How to override a Chef cookbook version constraint in an environment?

Tags: chef-infra

In my prod environment I have set a version constraint for a certain cookbook.

```
SampleCookbook = 1.1.4
```

Now I would like to get rid of this constraint. How can I do this incrementally? What I do not want to do is just deleting the constraint, because this will affect all machines in this environment at once.

I would rather disable the constraint on a signle node in to check if the change is safe, before I disable it in the environment. 
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a staging environment. Either test the update on a separate node in staging, or temporarily move one node to 'staging' environment - a copy of production with the constraint removed - test the update, remove constraint in production, move the node back.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to override the constraint for a single node - the environment is a closed entity. There may be some tools (knife plugins) to make such process easier, e.g. by letting you create a clone of existing environment on the fly.